# SQL Error : Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql

I've got the following piece of code which exectues within no problem

```
SELECT (
   CASE WHEN 
       (SELECT DateDiff (Day, (
        SELECT ChildDOB1 FROM MatterDataDef Where ptMatter = $Matter$), 
        GETDATE()))>6574 THEN '(over 18)' 
   ELSE '(' + ChildDOB1 + ')' 
   END)  
FROM dbo.MatterDataDef WHERE ptMatter = $Matter$
```

Howeveer, when i attempt to wrap the code in brackets (so i can use it as part of a longer equation) i get the following error 'Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string'

any help appreciated :)

Comment: what is the format of data in ChildDOB1, is it a datetime?

Comment: @cyberkiwi - doesn't James state it in his last line ?

Comment: @Jason Jong - which last line? do you mean the error text? The error could also occur if childdob1 itself is not datetime, because datediff is happening first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN Datediff (DAY, childdob1, Getdate()) > 6574
           THEN '(over 18)'
           ELSE '(' + convert(varchar,childdob1) + ')'
         END
FROM   dbo.matterdatadef
WHERE  ptmatter = $matter$
```

This is equivalent to your code. The extra subquery and brackets are all unnecessary.
The problem is that you are adding childdob1 (datetime) to the brackets without converting to varchar.  But did you actually want the DOB in a particular format, or the age?

Comment: thanks, thts got it working (plus thanks again for striping down my code for me, i'm new to sql and nice to learn new things)... dateformat i've got convert(varchar(10),childdob1, 103) ;)

Answer (score 1):

where you have

```
ELSE '(' + ChildDOB1 + ')'
```

you'll need to convert it to a character type.. ie varchar

```
ELSE '(' + cast(ChildDOB1 as varchar(50)) + ')'
```